# Migrate Queue from JBoss 4.2.3 to JBoss 5.1 AS

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, jboss5.x, jboss-4.2.x

I am trying to migrate my project from JBoss 4.2.3 (which was build by ant) to JBoss 5.1 AS (exploded version).

I managed to do most of it. But I cant figure the queue settings.

```
7:33:07,406 ERROR [JmsActivation] Unable to reconnect
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@11669f2(ra=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsResourceAdapter@2a4ec6
destination=mailSenderQueue 
destinationType=javax.jms.Queue tx=true
durable=false reconnect=10 provider=java:/DefaultJMSProvider user=null
maxMessages=1 minSession=1 maxSession=15 keepAlive=60000 useDLQ=true
DLQHandler=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.GenericDLQHandler
DLQJndiName=queue/DLQ DLQUser=null DLQMaxResent=5)
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: mailSenderQueue not bound   at
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)   at
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)   at
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)    at
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)   at
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)     at
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)     at
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)     at
org.jboss.util.naming.Util.lookup(Util.java:222)    at
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.setupDestination(JmsActivation.java:464)
    at
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.setup(JmsActivation.java:352)
    at
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.handleFailure(JmsActivation.java:292)
    at
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation$SetupActivation.run(JmsActivation.java:733)
    at org.jboss.resource.work.WorkWrapper.execute(WorkWrapper.java:205)
    at
org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.run(BasicTaskWrapper.java:260)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I have configured all the queues from the Console admin.